# Even after uninstalling mysql, i still have it in my UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I had many issues with MySQL software, even after uninstalling the files ten times, I still have it in my machine.
I want to remove everything because I have issues when I re-installing it.

The picture below is a screenshot after uninstalling all the MySQL packages.
[image]

I tried these commands :

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server
sudo apt purge mysql-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt remove dbconfig-mysql
```

Comment: Hello, your question might be better placed on https://superuser.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql\* mariadb\*
sudo apt clean
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_bak
sudo mv /etc/mysql /etc/mysql_bak
```

Done.